# Azure Policy - Setting up Alerts using Logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, policy

Is it possible to integrate the Azure Policy with Logic App for configuring Alerts and sending emails, when a Policy is non compliant and the service/resource created against it so that logic app gets triggered.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, we allow for alerts from Activity log. The log logic is different from new services that are non-compliant and when we do our periodic scan. We log when we do the evaluation and a resource is non-compliant. These alerts are subscription based.